# htaccess: how to redirect example.com/anything to script example.com/seoparser.php?anything

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

How to redirect `example.com/anything` to script `example.com/seoparser.php?anything` using `.htaccess`

This does not work:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.com/seoparser.php?$1
```

because of multiple redirection which ends on address `http://example.com/seoparser.php?seoparser.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to test if it is not already rewritten:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^seoparser\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$       /seoparser.php?$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if requested resource is not a file/directory and only then rewrite. For example:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) /seoparser.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```

Depending on circumstances (what rewrite logic you have in place/needs to be implemented) this can be much better solution than mentioned by @inti. You will see such combination of rules used in a lot of real applications (for example, WordPress, Magento) and PHP frameworks (most of the time they will have only internal routing logic).

This is a bit different approach (mostly from organisational point of view):

```
RewriteEngine On
# Do not do anything for already existing files
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]

# Your rewrite rules (file/folder does not exist, we may need to route it elsewhere)
RewriteRule (.*) /seoparser.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```